# print_r an insert statement php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this method to insert data into my database:

```
function insertMenue($content, $date) {
    $session = $_SESSION['aid'];
    global $pdo;
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
    $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO menue(type, content, date, creator) VALUE (?,?,?,?)');
    $query->bindValue(1, "menue");
    $query->bindValue(2, "<p>" . $content . "</p>");
    $query->bindValue(3, $date);
    $query->bindValue(4, $session);
    $query->execute(); 
}
```

I'm calling this method for every object in an array. Now every time when there should be a String which contains an umlaut (ä, ö, ü) the String gets cut off where the umlaut should be.

As for example I'm writing:

```
<p>Salat<br>Gemüse und Teigwaren</p>
```

The data in the database happens to be just:

```
<p>Salat<br>Gem
```

Now the question is:

1. How can I print_r() the whole sql statement?

   print_r($query->execute());

Would display (1,1,1,1)

and I want something like:
(menue, (p)Salat(br)Gemüse und Teigwaren(/p), 2015-09-06, 2)

I'm not sure whether it doesn't get to the database or whether the database is the problem.
The db itself can handle umlaute and is written in utf-8. I dumped the file and took a closer look at it, it shouldn't be corrupted.

Comment: You could print `$date` and `$session` before it gets to the SQL block - but take a look at the docuemtation for PHP PDO-  http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php - try stipulating the type that you are wanting to insert (e.g. `$query->bindValue(1, "menue", PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: If you're using true prepared statements right through to the database, there is no "whole statement". You have your query with placeholders, and you have your values. The problem is almost certainly an encoding problem, you're not actually sending UTF-8 encoded data to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant see the full query, because it doesnt exist in the PHP side.

PHP first sends the query and then the parameters when using prepared statements
*(Not sure what happens when the emulation mode is on though).*

If you want to see the final query, you should enable your database's query log and check there.

This is the closest you can get with just PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
function insertMenue($content, $date) {

    $session = $_SESSION['aid'];

    global $pdo;
    $pdo->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $params = ["menue", "<p>$content</p>", $date, $session];

    // Check all your params are set...
    // Although you may want to consider checking these before entering this block
    print_r($params);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO menue( type
                             , content
                             , date
                             , creator
                             )
            VALUES( ?
                  , ?
                  , ?
                  , ?
                  )";
    try {
        $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute($params); 
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new pdoDbException($e);
    }

}
```

Comment: @rootatwc is correct also - but you can get an exception (if you check for PDOException) if your params aren't set (which will point you in the right direction).